# Read shared preference of another android application

Tags: java, android

I need to access the Shared Preference file of another application. (**The device is rooted!**) Currently I seem to be facing a permission issues. Here is the current code that I run:

```
Context con = createPackageContext("com.sam.sample", CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
SharedPreferences sharedPref = con.getSharedPreferences("namefile", MODE_PRIVATE);
Map data = sharedPref.getString("name", "");
Log.d("Name", "name:" + name);
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Attempt to read preferences file **/data/data/com.sam.sample/shared_prefs/namefile.xml** without permission

I have also tried to run `su` command but I dont want the user to be notified that I want to get read access with `chmod 775` on the XML file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To do this when creating SharedPreference in "com.sam.sample" it should be created using Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE mode. So if you have code of "com.sam.sample" application, it should look something like below

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("namefile",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("name", strShareValue);
        editor.commit();
```

Also note that changing the mode to Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is not recommended as it may lead to security holes. As of NOS this will throw SecurityException. More info:-

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Ideally ContentProvider should be used.

For example query function of your ContentProvider can be

`MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "name" }, 1);
            cursor.addRow(new Object[] { readSharedPreference() });
            return cursor;`

Comment: Is there a way that I can access SharedPreferences with ContentResolver ?

Comment: Yes just return cursor(usually MatrixCursor) having sharedpreference data from query function of ContentProvider. See sample query function in modified answer